# Book Recommendation for Mathematical Statistics

Tags: references

Hi I am first year undergrad with math background, next year I will be starting a course in [introductory mathematical statistics at the University of Toronto](http://www.utstat.utoronto.ca/philip/courses/sta257/outline.html),
and the textbook the university uses, *Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis* by Rice, has received very poor ratings both from past students and online. So I was hoping if someone can give me a list of books that I can use instead? (And also hopefully cover the sequel to the course as well.)

Here's a copy of the syllabus ([pdf](http://fisher.utstat.toronto.edu/~hadas/STA261/course%20outline.pdf)).

Right now I have found two books that may help:

1. Statistical Inference, by Casella
2. Problems in Probability Theory Mathematical Statistics and Theory of Random Functions

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend "Mathematical Statistics" by Terrell,

which, I think, is not well-known.

[http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Unified-Introduction-Springer/dp/0387986219/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1366293457&sr=8-1&keywords=mathematical+statistics+terrell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387986219)

It's very concise(it might be too concise to understand it easily)

and covers almost everything, but not deeply.